# Rearrange one column into a two column data frame r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a large file that is organised in a very inconvenient manner, all values in one column  with seven values per cell, except for the last two rows, like this:

```
df <- c('(98440=9) (98450=9) (98500=9) (98520=9) (98530=9) (98540=9) (98550=9)',
'(98555=9) (98560=9) (98570=9) (98590=9) (98600=9) (98620=9) (98630=9)',
'(98690=9) (98920=3) (98930=5) (98940=5) (98950=9) (98990=11) (99900=-1)',
'(99910=11) (99920=-1) (99930=11)',
'(-1=-1) (-2=-1) (99999=-1)')
```

I only want to keep the numerical values and at the same time split the first and second numerical values into two columns, where '=' is the separator, like:

```
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1 98440     9
2 98450     9
3 98500     9
```

I managed two achieve this using separate in dplyr, substring, and some other code. However, I ended up losing a lot of data. Any ideas on how to fix this and keep all the data? I understand that this is a frequently asked question, but this dataset is a bit more messy than anything else that I've seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions:

Here's a two-step solution using `str_extract`from the package `stringr`.

First step - split the value chains into single values:

```
df1 <- unlist(strsplit(df, " "))
```

Second step - split the values at `=` and assign the value halves to two columns of a new dataframe:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  col1 = str_extract(df1, "(-)?\\d+(?==)"),
  col2 = str_extract(df1, "(?<==)(-)?\\d+")
)
```

Alternatively, here's a one-step solution using `str_extract_all`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  col1 = unlist(str_extract_all(df, "(-)?\\d+(?==)")),
  col2 = unlist(str_extract_all(df, "(?<==)(-)?\\d+"))
)
```

EDIT:

If the data is part of a dataframe, with the to-be-split data called `Var1`, the code would be this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  col1 = unlist(str_extract_all(df$Var1, "(-)?\\d+(?==)")),
  col2 = unlist(str_extract_all(df$Var1, "(?<==)(-)?\\d+"))
)
```

Result:

```
df2
    col1 col2
1  98440    9
2  98450    9
3  98500    9
4  98520    9
5  98530    9
6  98540    9
7  98550    9
8  98555    9
9  98560    9
10 98570    9
11 98590    9
12 98600    9
13 98620    9
14 98630    9
15 98690    9
16 98920    3
17 98930    5
18 98940    5
19 98950    9
20 98990   11
21 99900   -1
22 99910   11
23 99920   -1
24 99930   11
25    -1   -1
26    -2   -1
27 99999   -1
```

Comment: Sorry guys, but I forgot to mention that the data is organised in a data frame. How would the code look if the df <- data.frame(df) was added after the value?

Answer (score 1):

Classically, using `gsub` and `strsplit`.

```
df <- 
  data.frame(matrix(as.double(unlist(strsplit(gsub("[\\(\\)]", "", v), "=|\\s"))),,2, b=T))

#       V1 V2
# 1  98440  9
# 2  98450  9
# 3  98500  9
# 4  98520  9
# 5  98530  9
# 6  98540  9
# 7  98550  9
# 8  98555  9
# 9  98560  9
# 10 98570  9
# 11 98590  9
# 12 98600  9
# 13 98620  9
# 14 98630  9
# 15 98690  9
# 16 98920  3
# 17 98930  5
# 18 98940  5
# 19 98950  9
# 20 98990 11
# 21 99900 -1
# 22 99910 11
# 23 99920 -1
# 24 99930 11
# 25    -1 -1
# 26    -2 -1
# 27 99999 -1
```

---

*Data*

```
v <- c("(98440=9) (98450=9) (98500=9) (98520=9) (98530=9) (98540=9) (98550=9)", 
"(98555=9) (98560=9) (98570=9) (98590=9) (98600=9) (98620=9) (98630=9)", 
"(98690=9) (98920=3) (98930=5) (98940=5) (98950=9) (98990=11) (99900=-1)", 
"(99910=11) (99920=-1) (99930=11)", "(-1=-1) (-2=-1) (99999=-1)"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inconveniently arranged untidy data is what the tidyverse was designed for!

```
library(tidyverse)

c('(98440=9) (98450=9) (98500=9) (98520=9) (98530=9) (98540=9) (98550=9)',
  '(98555=9) (98560=9) (98570=9) (98590=9) (98600=9) (98620=9) (98630=9)',
  '(98690=9) (98920=3) (98930=5) (98940=5) (98950=9) (98990=11) (99900=-1)',
  '(99910=11) (99920=-1) (99930=11)',
  '(-1=-1) (-2=-1) (99999=-1)') %>%

  purrr::map(~ str_split(.," ")) %>% # split each string into its individual components

  unlist() %>%

  tibble::enframe(NULL,"Numbers") %>%

  dplyr::mutate(Numbers = str_replace_all(Numbers,"[()]","")) %>% # remove the brackets as they are unnecessary

  tidyr::separate(Numbers,c("Number 1","Number 2"),sep = "=") # separate using "=" as the separator
```

The same code works if you pass a dataframe into it in the first step instead of a character vector.